# I want to count the number of entries made in a particular column in multiple excel sheets on present day. What could a possible solution?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to count the number of entries made in a particular column(s) in multiple sheets on present day through VBA

***Example of my data:***
[image]

Here I want to write a code which can help me count the number of RPCs on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to code it yorself before asking for help on here, we help people whos code is not working, but it was a simple bit of coding to do for you.

You will need to change the columns which it is looking down, from the screenshot it is column J but it may be different

```
Sub CodeForUser()

Dim LastRow As Long

Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Select 'change coloumn if needed
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row
[A1].Select 'change coloumn if needed

Do Until ActiveCell.Row >= LastRow

    If ActiveCell.Value = "RPC 1&2" Then ' if there is more than just RPC 1&2 you will need to do is remov the "then" and add "And ActiveCell.Value = "what everelse you want" and then add then to the end
    X = X + 1
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
'displays message box showing how many RPCs there are
MsgBox ("Number of RPCs is " & X)

End Sub
```